# Where can I find Bootstrap Full API Documentation?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I read a Book about Bootstrap while it mentioned in on of the examples some code that I can not find where it is in documentation.

```
<div id="cat1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
```

So what does `in` in the CSS mean and where can I find the full API Documentation? Thanks.

Comment: Firstly, all docs should be on Bootstrap website. Secondly, asking for external resources is off topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: this is the official website for bootstrap and the full documentation of the framework also the site has many practical examples built with bootstrap itself

http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

The collapsible content is hidden per default. If you add the `.in class` the content will be shown by default. Taking a look at the source code in `bootstrap.css` tells us:

```
.collapse.in {
  display: block;
}
```

For more information see http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Comment: Not me, but you should not answer an off-topic question.